# What is the generalized solution to $M = \int_0^1 (1-x^m)^n$?

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, definite-integrals

What is the generalized solution to $$M = \int_0^1 (1-x^m)^n \,dx$$
(where it can be expressed in terms of n and m) and m and n are rational numbers if considering m and n as natural numbers makes calculations easier use them.

Are there methods which solves **M** without the use of Beta function?

[Here, Beta function being referred to as $\beta$(m,n) = $\int_0^1 x^{m-1}(1-x)^{n-1}$ dx = $\frac{\Gamma(m)\Gamma(n)}{\Gamma(m+n)}$]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, from the binomial theorem
$$(1-x^m)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n\choose k}(-1)^kx^{km}$$
thus
$$\int_0^1(1-x^m)^n\,dx=\int_0^1\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n\choose k}(-1)^kx^{km}\,dx=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n\choose k}(-1)^k\frac{x^{km+1}}{km+1}\bigg|^1_0=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n\choose k}(-1)^k\frac{1}{km+1}$$
which according to [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%5Csum_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5E%7Bn%7D%7B%7Bn%5Cchoose%20k%7D%28-1%29%5Ek%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bkm%2B1%7D%7D) equals $\frac{\frac{1}{m}!n!}{(\frac1m+n)!}$.

But since these are generalized factorials, these make use of the $\Gamma$ function, so this is equivalent to your $\beta$ function solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this as closed form
$$\int_0^{1}(1-x^m)^n\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\Gamma\left(1+\frac{1}{m}\right)\Gamma\left(1+n\right)}{\Gamma\left(1+n+\frac{1}{m}\right)}$$

Comment: $m$ and $n$ are real numbers ($m\neq 0$). In case $n\in\mathbb{N}$ you have $\Gamma(1+n)=n!$